# The ring of integral elements of $L$ with $L/K$ Galois.

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension,$G:=Gal(L/K)$.

"Given $a$ in the ring $O$ of integral elements of $L$, the conjugate $\sigma(a)$, for every $\sigma\in G$, also belongs to $O$, i.e., $G$ acts on $O$ "[enter link description here](https://books.google.com/books?id=hS3qCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=The%20%22ramification%20theory%22%20that%20arises%20from%20this%20assumption%20has%20been%20introduced%20into%20number%20theory%20by%20DAVID%20HILBERT&source=bl&ots=TZHYA_qZJn&sig=UYUCayyh4bY-z1SqXJh-lOVl4KM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSmfnS67XTAhUn6YMKHb4hAcYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=The%20%22ramification%20theory%22%20that%20arises%20from%20this%20assumption%20has%20been%20introduced%20into%20number%20theory%20by%20DAVID%20HILBERT&f=false)

I feel confused with this claim, my question lies on what the definition of the $O$ here is in the claim, does that mean the set of elements of $L$ that are integral over $K$?

Comment: This is probably in the context where $K$,$L$ are Dedekind domains, and then $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_L$ would mean the elements of $L$ that are integral over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here $\mathcal O = \mathcal O_L$ denotes the set of all elements of $L$ that are integral over the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ of $K$ (for instance if $L/K$ is an extension of number fields).

The claim is that if $x \in \mathcal O_L$, then $\sigma(x) \in \mathcal O_L$, for any $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.
This is easy to prove: if $$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0$$ for some $a_i \in \mathcal O_K$, then
$$\sigma(x)^n+\sigma(a_{n-1})\sigma(x)^{n-1}+\dots+\sigma(a_0)=0$$ and $\sigma(a_i) = a_i \in \mathcal O_K$, since $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, which shows that $\sigma(x)$ also lies in $\mathcal O_L$.